# Обработка формы на всех страницах layout Yii2 через виджет

Tags: yii2

Здравствуйте. Есть форма подписки, она располагается в footer'е, соотвественно нужна её обработка на всех страницах, где используется текущий layouts.

[image: скрин формы подписки]

По информации, которую я нашёл, лучше всего делать через виджет. Но не могу понять, как правильно это реализовать.

Виджет в данном случае будет выступать, как некий интегрированный контроллер? Логику обработки нужно вписывать в него? Как передавать данные в модель формы, к примеру?

Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хочется создать виджет то можно сделать следующее:

**1.** Создать папку виджетов.

Если используете шаблон *basic*, можно создать папку `widgets` в корне проекта и помещать виджеты туда, если шаблон *advanced* - рекомендую создать папку `widgets` внутри папки `common`.

**2.** Создать папку с виджетом внутри папки `widgets`.

Простейшая структура виджета:

`widgets
    subscribe
      views
        form.php
      SubscribeWidget.php`

Здесь папка `subscribe` - будет являться нашей папкой для виджета. Внутри неё будет папка `views` со всеми вьюхами. В корне папки распологается класс самого виджета. В данном случае это файл `SubscribeWidget.php`.

**3.** Написать код виджета.

Примерный минимальный код виджета:

```
<?php
namespace app\widgets\subscribe;

class SubscribeWidget extends \yii\base\Widget
{
    public function init()
    {
        return parent::init();
    }

    public function run()
    {
        /*
         * Какое-либо действие, логика, создание модели и тд
         */

        return $this->render('subscribe/form', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Здесь мы инициируем наш виджет и рендерим вьюху с формой подписки.

Для обработки формы можно создать обычный контроллер, или использовать Ваш `SiteController`, или придумать любой другой вариант.

**4.** Вызвать виджет внутри лайаута.

Код вызова получившегося виджета:

```
<?=\app\widgets\subscribe\SubscribeWidget::widget()?>
```

Answer (score 1):

При создании формы укажите явно action. Например так:

```
Html::beginForm(
    Url::to(['/site/subscribe'])
);
Html::input('string', 'email');
Html::submitButton('Подписаться');
Html::endForm();
```

Ну и в контроллере Site создать действие actionSubscribe, где будут обрабатываться данные.

Comment: Хм, а куда передавать модель? В каждом action её передавать придётся?

Comment: Да, точно. Тогда лучше реализовать без использования модели. Изменила ответ